# Probability of die threshold

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose there is a fair die with $n$ faces labeled from $1$ to $n$, and a number $1\leq k \leq n$.

How many times does one need to throw the die (on average) to get a number $j$ with $j\geq k$?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Might help to think of this as a simple Binomial process with success probability $p$.  Of course, you have to compute $p$ first.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "to get a number" are you talking about the sum of all previous?  Or are you talking about an individual result.  For instance, we might talk about the number of rolls it requires on average on a six-sided die to get a sum greater than $20$., or we might talk about the number of rolls it requires on average on a six-sided die to get a five or a six as one of the results...

Comment: Think of it as an unfair coin with probability of a head being ${n-k+1 \over n}$. How many times do you need to toss to get a head? The outcomes are $H, TH,TTH,...$. This suggests the distribution @lulu mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of times the die is thrown until a number $j$ with $j\geqslant k$ is obtained. Then $X$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $(n-k+1)/n$. So the probability mass function of $X$ is given by
$$
\mathbb P(X=m) = (1-(n-k+1)/n)^{m-1}(n-k+1)/n.
$$ 
We compute the expectation by 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty m\cdot\mathbb P(X=m)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(1-(n-k+1)/n)^{m-1}(n-k+1)/n\\
&= \frac n{n-k+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you elaborate why the geometric distribution is the correct one? For those who are not very skilled in probability theory.

Comment: Is this correct? For k=n it seems like the die has to be thrown "on avarage" $1/2$ times

Comment: Think of it as an unfair coin with probability of heads being $\frac{n-k+1}n$, as @copper.hat mentioned in the comments to your original question.

Comment: Oh, I had a typo. It is supposed to be $\frac n{n-k+1}$.